# Using font character substitutions in CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, glyph-substitution

I'm trying to access some alternative character glyphs using [this font](https://www.fontfabric.com/fonts/baron/) at the moment.

The font's character subs are named like this: "A.alt", "A.alt1", "B.alt" etc. so they don't have a unicode to go after.

I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-alternates) but when using Inspect Element the CSS-property just returns a "Unknown Property Name"-error. Any other way to do this?

```
<html>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Glyph-test</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            font-family: Baron neue;
            
        }
        h1 span.A-alt {
            font-variant-alternates: character-variant(A.alt);
        }
    </style>
    
    
    <h1>Testing alternative <span class="A-alt">A</span></h1>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you test it with Firefox or Safari? It looks like they are currently the only browsers that support font-variant-alternates: http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-variant-alternates

Comment: I tried Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `font-variant-alternates` you can use [`font-feature-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings) to achieve that. Set it to [`"salt"`](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/features_pt.htm#salt) or `"salt" 2` or `"salt" 3` (and so on) according to which alternative you want to use.

Your CSS code could look like this:

```css
h1 span.A-alt {
    font-feature-settings: "salt" 2;
}
```

Comment: Damn rad'! Thanks for that mate.

Comment: Is it possible to combine this with the data-variant-function below?

Comment: I don’t think so. But you could create CSS classes like `alt-1`, `alt-2` and so on, and use them for different characters. You will probably need not more than `alt-5` or so.

Comment: Yes, figured that out :) Thanks anyway, googled like crazy to find something on this.

Comment: You can find more information about font settings in the Typekit help from Adobe: https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/open-type-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way without the need of extra spans:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: local('MyFont');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont-Alt';
    font-feature-settings: "salt"; 
    /* Above can vary depending on the font. For example:
        font-feature-settings: "aalt"; 
        font-feature-settings: "ss01";
    */
    src: local('MyFont');
    unicode-range: U+004d,U+004f ; /* Unicode values of the original characters. */
}

body{
    font-family: 'MyFont-Alt','MyFont';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The best way according to me is by making use of the `data-` attributes of HTML5 .

In your case you could implement it like so:

```
<html>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Glyph-test</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            font-family: Baron neue;

        }
        h1 span.A-alt {
            font-variant-alternates: character-variant(attr(data-variant));
        }
    </style>


    <h1>Testing alternative <span class="A-alt" data-variant="A.alt">A</span></h1>
</html>
```

You can implement the `character-variant(attr(data-variant))` however you want it, but you get the point right. The value you pass via HTML & use that same value in your CSS using `attr(data-name)`

Comment: Well, that is really neat when the property actually works, which it doesn't seem to do. My main problem now is just accessing the alternative glyph

Comment: This is what your caniuse link says. - "CSS Values and Units Level 3 adds the ability to use attr() **on any CSS property, not just content**, and to use it for non-string values (e.g. numbers, colors)." Can you even read your own suggestions more carefully before downvoting ?? Flaging your comment for now

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa You are right, that is what caniuse says. But if you take a closer look you can see that not a single browser supports that feature. That is what I wanted to point out, sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: For people reading this discussion (since my original comment was deleted) this is the link we are talking about: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr